# group by same column where multiple condition using same column input

Tags: php, mysql

i have a table named temp. columns are id, telco, shortcode,hotkey.

```
id  telco  shortcode hotkey
1    asdf    123      ib
2    gra     123      sb
3    cc      123      sb
4    bl      123      ibb
```

using mysql query i want output count(shortcode) group by telco where hotkey ib shortcode 123 and 
count(shortcode) group by telco where hotkey sb shortcode 123

```
telco   ib         sb 
asdf     1         0
gra      0         1
cc       0         1
bl       1         0
```

if i use  the following query

```
SELECT COUNT(`shortcode`) WHERE `hotkey` = 'ib' AND `shortcode` = 123
SELECT COUNT(`shortcode`) WHERE `hotkey` = 'sb' AND `shortcode` = 123
```

then i get out in the following way

```
telco   ib          

asdf     1         
gra      0         
cc       0         
bl       1     

telco   sb

asdf     1         
gra      0         
cc       0         
bl       1
```

but i don't want this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you want to use sum case like

```
 Select
      Telco,
       Sum  (   Case when hotkey = 'ib' then 1 else 0 end) as ib,
       Sum  (   Case when hotkey = 'sb' then 1 else 0 end) as sb
From 
      Yourtable 
 Group By
   Telco
```

Note current versions of Oracle an Sql server have the option to use the pivot syntax

Comment: I wrote "Theb" when I was supposed to write "then". I fixed that but the error you get is strange. I'm not sure what could cause it. Perhaps you should make sure everything is escaped and start with just one SUM / Case statement

Comment: Glad I could help. You might want to check out this meta post. It explains the benefits of marking an answer accepted. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

You pretty much have it already, just need to throw the SELECT in and don't worry about the GROUP BY bit.

```
SELECT COUNT(`shortcode`) WHERE `hotkey` = 'ib' AND `shortcode` = 123
SELECT COUNT(`shortcode`) WHERE `hotkey` = 'sb' AND `shortcode` = 123
```

The first will give you how many rows have hotkey as 'ib' and shortcode as 123, the second with hotkey as 'sb' and shortcode as 123.

Comment: i know it , but  how to show output my required format. i want to write mysql query that give above format output

Comment: May want to clarify that in the question. Rather than COUNT(shortcode) you could change it to selecting telco instead, and then just loop through and display for each query.

Comment: display each query then telco show each time, like below                  telco   ib          
asdf     1         
gra      0         
cc       0         
bl       1  and telco   sb
asdf     0,         
gra      1 , cc  1 b1  0  but i want to show telco name only one for each query.